# allow twitterbootstrap class-attributes on span and p tags in ckeditor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ckeditor

for my cms I want to edit content with bootstrap-styles. when I edit source-code in ckeditor and add class attributes it gets stripped off by switching to wysiwyg-mode.

```
<p class="lead">bla</p>   =>   <p>bla</p>
```

from the docs I can't find a way to allow class-attributes with any value to p-tags.

my config very much default:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = (config) ->
  config.language = 'de'
  config.contentsCss = '/assets/front/application.css'
  config.format_div = { element : 'div', attributes : {'data-no-turbolink' : 'true'}}

  config.toolbar_Pure = [
    { name: 'document',    items: [ 'Source','-','Save','NewPage','DocProps','Preview','Print','-','Templates' ] },
    { name: 'clipboard',   items: [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
    { name: 'editing',     items: [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','SpellChecker', 'Scayt' ] },
    { name: 'tools',       items: [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks','-','About' ] }
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', items: [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph',   items: [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','CreateDiv','-','JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl' ] },
    { name: 'links',       items: [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
    '/',
    { name: 'styles',      items: [ 'Styles','Format','Font','FontSize' ] },
    { name: 'colors',      items: [ 'TextColor','BGColor' ] },
    { name: 'insert',      items: [ 'Image','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak' ] },
  ]
  config.toolbar = 'Pure'
  true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add all or chosen classes to allowed content.

```
// Allow all classes for all allowed elements.
config.extraAllowedContent = '*(*)';

// Or allow class1 and class2 for listed block elements and class3 for listed inline ones.
config.extraAllowedContent = 'p,h1,h2,h3(class1,class2); img,strong,em(class3)';
```

Read more about Advanced Content Filter here: [Advanced Content Filter guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter).

Comment: I'm able to add span-tags with style-attributes. If I add a line-height in the stlye-attribute it gets stripped off. Where do I configure css-style-rules?

Comment: See the [allowed content rules guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules).